# Writing an SNMP Agent for Windows: SnmpAPI.Lib or MgmtAPI.lib?

Tags: windows, snmp, agent

I need to write an SNMP agent on Windows for our company product.

SnmpApi.lib - It's my understanding that SnmpApi.lib allows you to create a full agent from scratch and probably requires more work. This, however, takes over the SNMP port and doesn't allow other agents to run and will take longer to code.

MgmtAPI.lib - This lib will allow one to create an extension to the already running Windows SNMP service and seems a more elegant approach to creating an Windows agent. However, I'm findining very little official MS documentation/examples on how to code such an agent. I've also read on another forum that this might be deprecated.

I've seen an Oreilly book out in the wild called "Windows NT SNMP" but I heard it uses deprecated libs or techniques. I don't know if this is true or not.

I've also seen libraries like SNMP++ that use the SnmpAPI.lib to create an agent, but again, this isn't as elegant as letting multiple sub-agents on the system via MgmtAPI.lib, it seems.

*A few questions:*

**I heard that MgmtAPI.lib is legacy/deprecated. Is this true?**

**What's the best practice for creating a Windows SNMP agent?**

**What library should i be using?**

**Any other suggestions?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default windows SNMP stack and framework is very limited in its ability.  Unfortunately, your best solutions are probably found elsewhere (of which there are a number of external libraries and stacks).  If you want one that is modular and allows sub-agents, then look into a stack that supports the AgentX protocol.  That's a standardized SNMP subagent protocol and will let multiple sub-agents attach to a master agent.

But whatever you do, please pick a stack that supports SNMPv3 and use the security in it.

If you want a random stack example that is known to work well on windows, try [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) which is fairly popular among the "replace the SNMP stack on windows" crowd.  But I'm also biased and associated with the project, so I'll end with saying: "it doesn't matter too much; pick any stack that supports both AgentX and SNMPv3".

Comment: Thank you, Wes. Do you know though if Net-SNMP supports the standard Windows MIBs that the MS SNMP Agent service supports? I'd love to switch to Net-SNMP, but I'm not sure if it's an option for me. I'm actually using Net-SNMP and smilint to do some of my MIB work.

Comment: It doesn't support any MS specific MIBs, but it does support more of the standard MIBs that MS itself does.  Worst case, if you run the MS agent on a different port, you can actually get the Net-SNMP master agent to "proxy" to it for anything it is running that Net-SNMP doesn't support.  See the snmpd.conf manual page on "proxy".

Comment: I might try that. Right now, I'm coding my MIB and trying to get a well designed data-structure in my C++ subagent DLL that represents the MIB. This is very frustrating and time consuming. Could I more easily use the Net-SNMP suite to create a Net-SNMP subagent and the MIB compiler? My manager is also worried about not seeing the standard RFC MIBs that the MS agent currently reports.

Comment: Well, run snmpwalk on both and compare the differences.  You could do that in 10 minutes and have a fairly detailed report for your manager to look through.

Comment: Wes, I did that. I liked what I saw. Now I'm exploring on how to make a simple MIB similar to IFTables and with the AgentX to build an extension subagent. Do you know an easy way to translate the MIB to C, C++ or Perl code that I can use in an AgentX subagent? That would be ideal and save time. My data struct to model our device is what seems will be the killer. Thank you for your expertise! I'll make that into an SO question you can answer if you want.

Comment: The `mib2c` program that comes with Net-SNMP will translate a mib table into a number of things (the 'c' is a misnomer...  it should be named `mib2anything`).  See the Net-SNMP wiki for ideas and examples.